# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore') is shown using filepond with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, filepond

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore') is shown when using filepond on nextjs, works fine when using reactjs
The Page Error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnpc3.png)
My Code:-

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { FilePond } from 'react-filepond';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <FilePond/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

To Recreate the error simply create a fresh nextjs app then, include the libraries 'filepond' & 'react-filepond' then just use the Filepond Component as in the code above.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. What version of Next.js and Filepond are you using?

Comment: filepond is 4.30.3, react-filepond is 7.1.1, nextjs is 12.1.5

Comment: Is it possible you have a `<StrictMode>` tag somewhere in the tree? For some reason this causes the FilePond component to fail on init.

Comment: NextJS comes with React set to strict mode, just turned it off, now it works. Thank You!